# JCombobox - change value in JTable

Tags: java, swing, combobox

first post here.

How to write method which can change values in JTable when app is on running? getValIn() returns me values in english (i used ResourceBundle for that and its work), but if i change the combobox I want have this value in french in JTable.
It's a piece of code.

```
public void show(){
    String[] lang = {"en", "fr"};
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    Object[][] obj;
    
    JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox(lang);
    
    combobox.setSelectedIndex(0);
    combobox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(combobox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("en")){
                selectedLang ="en";
            }else{
                selectedLang = "fr";
            }
        }
    });
    
    obj = getValIn(selectedLang);

TableModel tb= new DefaultTableModel(obj, columns.toArray());
    JTable table = new JTable(tb);
```

It's not necessary to be in JCombobox.
Thanks, have a nice day!

Comment: Well, the answer would depend on how you model and renders are setup.  In the simplest solution, you would set the renders to use the appropriate language and simply trigger the `JTable` to do a complete reload, but since we don't have a complete picture of your implementation, it's difficult to provide a reasonable answer

Comment: FYI - `AbstractTableModel` includes a number of `fireXxx` event methods which will cause parts or all of the table be reloaded (`DefaultTableModel` extends from `AbstractTableModel`)

Comment: ok thanks, ill try to find out how to reload those JTable, In GUI i have only JTable with Strings and JCombobox so i didn't add Jframe etc staff